# $\int_0^4|x^3-2x^2-x+2|dx$ I didn't get the correct end result and I'm searching after the bad step in my solution.

Tags: calculus, integration

Well, as I calculated, that $(x^3-2x^2-x+2)$ is equal to $(x-2)(x-1)(x+1)$, so I have to check where is $(x^3-2x^2-x+2)dx\ge0$ $\implies$ $(x-2)(x-1)(x+1)\ge0$ and I get the intervals of $(-1;1)\cup(2;\infty)$.

After that I can rewrite the original expression:

$\int_0^4 |x^3-2x^2-x+2|dx$=

$\int_0^1 (x^3-2x^2-x+2)dx$+$\int_1^2-(x^3-2x^2-x+2)dx+\int_2^4 (x^3-2x^2-x+2)dx$, as an end result I get 30.5, and I don't know what I did wrong in my calculation because of the end result should be $\frac{133}{6}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct, and the three integrals are correct, so the mistake must be in calculating them. I calculated them, and got the results
$$
\frac{13}{12},\quad\frac{5}{12},\quad\text{and}\quad \frac{62}{3}
$$
respectively. You do not mention what you get, but I assume something different. The fractions above add up to $133/6$.

Comment: I really mad a mistake by the calculation,thank you for your comment.